# Spring Framework реальные приложения

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Хочу посмотреть как работают и из чего состоят реальные проекты.
То-есть меня интересует не именно исходники на гитхабе(там я всеравно ничего не понимаю не в своем коде, так там еще и сложный код), а просто примеры популярных сервисов, которые написаны на Java+Spring.
Тоесть допустим stackoverflow на .net. А что делают на Spring? все так его хвалят, я его учу, многие считают его мощнейшим фреймворком, но что же сделано уже на нем?(кроме офф сайта spring.io и пары опенсоурс мелких проектов, о которых без гуглинга "open source projects Spring" не увидишь.

Answer (score 4):

Вам так сложно найти примеры потому, что вы не там ищете. На Spring по большей части разрабатывают не сайты, а корпоративные системы, типа интернет-банкинга Альфа-Банка или ВТБ, платформы электронной коммерции SAP Hybris, CRM QIWI collection и т.п.

Comment: а что-то не русское? так как я не россиянин, а не зная таких компаний, я мало чего пойму)
может что-то интернациональное

Comment: SAP - это не русская компания. Это крупнейший в мире производитель систем автоматизации бизнеса с головным офисом в Германии.

Comment: То есть такие приложения как Rest Api не делают, а только пытаются его хайпить, но пока условные php, ruby, python и тд более популярны, чтобы делать всякие телеграмы, фейсбуки, твитч и тд? Просто мне больше интересны такие приложения, чем бизнес-нонейм приложения, о которых обычные люди не знают. Конечно интересно делать бизнес приложения, но на таком быстро прогоришь как разработчик, ибо нет мотивации писать код

Comment: RESTful API ещё как делают. Facebook по большей части использует самописанные сервисы на базе Netty. Основные сервисы Twitch - это Go. Что использует Telegram мне неизвестно, но готов ручаться, что это не платформы не на базе интерпретируемых языков.

Comment: Ну я же про Java(а конкретней Spring). 
только повикипедил Netty, я так понял это фреймворк как Spring?А почему он а не Spring?
Тоесть впринципе есть смысл углубляться в Spring, чтоб можно было стартап делать интересных веб приложений, которые не особо связанны с чистым бизнесом, у которых MVC с фронтендом на Jsp/Thymleaf(еще мне эти шаблонизаторы уж очень сложно даются, может там и простые вещи, но я почему-то не в состоянии самостоятельно написать хоть что-то на thymleaf, так как очень все сумбурно и хаотично, поэтому хочется только Rest Api делать и учить js фреймворк.

Comment: Netty - это более низкоуровневый фреймворк. Почти все ансихронные фреймворки на Java работают поверх него, включая Spring WebFlux. Такие нагрузки, как у Facebook, высокоуровневые фреймворки просто не вывозят. Смысл углублятся в Spring есть.

Comment: Я более менее хорошо понимаю структуру проекта: модель(entity класс), repository(интерфейс который имплементит jpa), service(в котором реализуются какие-то кастомные методы, которых нет в JpaRepository), и controller(где принимается объект и возвращается что-то.
Но вод с security беда, ничего не понятно, все примеры которые беру с ошибками, не запускаются(кроме тех, где тупо регистрация user-password, которая записана в конфиге, а не хранится через бд с ролями и тд

Comment: @ekstra777 не в тему может, но про БД - плюсую. Тоже долго не мог разобраться. Попробуй просмотреть **примитивный пример** [в данном гитхабе](https://github.com/Antonio112009/HibernateAuthenticationExample)